# graphics-card compatibility

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi, displayport

How can I connect and use two HP LP3065 monitors with an NVIDIA® Quadro® FX 4800 graphics card installed in a HP z800 computer?

Comment: Generally we plug 'em in. Why?

Answer (score 0):

These monitors are DVI only, correct?  You will need active DisplayPort to DVI converters to run at a full 2560x1600 resolution over the DisplayPort connections - [something like this](http://us.startech.com/product/DP2DVID-DisplayPort-to-DVI-Dual-Link-Active-Converter%E2%80%93USB-Powered) but you can probably get them a little cheaper.  (They are still rather expensive, though.)  This card has one DVI though, if I recall correctly, so you should only need one of these.